# Simple AngularJS controller does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I've searched and read all possible explanations, but none have helped so far.
The problem is that the data binding with the curly brackets doesn't work (it only works if I define the module and controller in the index.html).

index.html :

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" media="screen">
<script src="controllers/listcontroller.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="main">
<body data-ng-controller="ListController">
      <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="test in tests">
        <span>{{ test.name }}</span>
        <p>{{ test.type }}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    There are currently {{test.length}} tests available.
    You have currently selected 0 tests.
    <button class="animatedbutton"> Proceed </button>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js (in folder js):

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controller']);
})();
```

listcontroller.js (in folder controllers):

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myApp.controller');
app.controller('ListController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.tests = [
                      {'name': 'A',
                       'type': '1'},
                      {'name': 'B',
                       'type': '2'},];
}]);
})();
```

The view shows me something like this:

> - `{{ test.name }}`
>
> `{{ test.type }}`
>
> There are currently `{{test.length}}` tests available. 
>   You have currently selected 0 tests.

I've followed a couple of tutorials, such as the Angular in 60 Minutes, [AngularJS.org](http://www.AngularJS.org), and some on YT, but I always encounter the same problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several issues look at the plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/bnYAsGk273kO5znMnAJh

index.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>

  <script src="listcontroller.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ListController">
  <div class="main">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="test in tests">
        <span>{{ test.name }}</span>
        <p>{{ test.type }}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>

    There are currently {{test.length}} tests available. You have currently selected 0 tests.
    <button class="animatedbutton"> Proceed </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controller']);
})();
```

listcontroller.js

```
(function() {

  var ctr = angular.module('myApp.controller', []);
  ctr.controller('ListController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.tests = [{'name': 'A','type': '1'}, {'name': 'B','type': '2' }];
    }
  ]);
})();
```

Comment: did some changes but better you check the plunker

Answer (score -1):

You created a second module so you need to have the [] again:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.controller', []);
```

Can you also include the console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: thanks, though it didn't solve the problem. Here it is on plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/3TGzbd?p=preview